# Add datetime Value

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm searching for the best way to echo day numbers in a week.
First i need to check what week there is.
And then echo all dates of the week into variables.

This is what i got:

```
//This Week Variable dates
$this_year = date('Y');
$this_week_no = date('W');
$this_week_mon = new DateTime();
 $this_week_mon->setISODate($this_year,$this_week_no);
```

How do i rise tue by one day?

```
$this_week_tue = $this_week_mon ++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$this_week_mon->modify('+1 day');
```

or [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) which accepts a [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object:

```
$this_week_mon->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

You can loop through all of the days of the week using `DatePeriod()`:

```
$start = new DateTime();
$start->setISODate($this_year,$this_week_no);
$end   = clone $start;
$end->modify('+1 week');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('N');
}
```

Comment: I used your second example, but i got one problem. The variables ..mon and ..tue get´s the same P1D value?!

Comment: @StoneStreet Do this: `$this_week_tue = clone $this_week_mon;` and then `$this_week_tue->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));` or look at the newest edit. Both `add()` and `modify()` modify the existing object along with returning itself.

Comment: @StoneStreet What version of php are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this_week_mon->modify('+1 day');
```

Should increment `$this_week_mon` by one day. To increase by more, just use days;

```
$this_week_mon->modify('+27 day');
```

Would increment by 27 days.

Comment: If i use this: `$this_week_tue = $this_week_mon->modify('+1 day');` Bothe Variables gets the same value..

Comment: `$this_week_tue = $this_week_mon; $this_week_tue->modify('+1 day');` does that work?

Comment: @Stu: no, it will not, you cannot copy objects like that, use `clone` for copying objects.

Comment: Ah, yes of course! `$this_week_tue = clone $this_week_mon; $this_week_tue->modify('+1 day');` Thanks.